# How to dynamically choose and connect to Oracle through C# (Dev Vs Test Vs Production Server)

Tags: c#, oracle, connection-string

Our company is looking to change from a legacy system to rebuilding everything in C#.  Over the years we changed from our original database to having an Oracle backend.  And now we have a 3 layers environment of Development, Test and Production.  (We are at the beginning steps of training so this may be a stupid question.  But trying to make sure we follow a best practice from the start.)

Most of our programs are built like the Windows Forms application, not web based.  At the start of every applications, the developers choose if they want Development, Test or Production.  Certain users get Test or Production option.  So in essence they can run the exact same application from the same location with one session pointing at Test and one at Production.  Each application session stays connected to Oracle the whole time until the application is closed.  (We are planning on adapting better methods where we connect and disconnect versus always having sessions open.  We didn't really have the option in the past.)

As we are learning C#, we have tests connecting to our database and have that working. Another developer here was looking into setting up a *.config file that would be overwritten as they opened and answered the question. But I have been trying to find how others handle this sort of situation where you can open the same exe multiple times and go against whichever databases you choose.  My assumption is that you could have separate folders with the same *.exe in each with a different *.config.  But didn't know if this is really the most graceful way to accomplish this.

We know that we will have to deal with a lot of mindset changes instead of "Well this is how it used to work..."  Just want to make sure we start off the right method.

Answer (score 0):

We have eight test databases running on three oracle servers. Each database is linked to a different test version of our backend office along with a front end client facing web GUI and numerous of miscellaneous scripts. To handle this we set up eight different filesystems, one for each database, and wrote a simple script that mapped the filesystem to the users pc and copied the backoffice exes locally. So the user would just click on whatever database they wanted, the drive would get mapped and the exes copied down. Production is completely separate.

To be honest, this system is simple but it works well enough. Deploy new code to a central repository and ask users to remap their drives to pick up the new .exes. If somebody needs to retest an old version, they can just drop the exes locally rather than change the entire database everyone.

It might be worth creating another test instance for emergency patch testing that is an exact copy of production and a fourth instance for regression testing new releases before they hit production because test environments can quickly fall out of sync which makes regression a pain.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a lazy solution, but I have the same situation in our environment, and we resolve the issue by having three separate start-up projects, one for prod, test and development.  These projects are extremely lightweight and do nothing more than set an environment property launch the startup form, both of which are in the "real" project.

As an added bonus, this really simplifies our click-once deployments, as we can manage the builds independently of one another.

Thus far, I haven't encountered any disadvantages to this approach, although it's likely someone will tell me there is a better way.  If I hear it, I'm all ears.

In essence, though, I'm recommending that rather than have one application that can connect to any of the three environments, you have three different deployments of the same application.

To have a single app that can connect to multiple instances of a database really shouldn't be a big deal -- if that's really what you want...  Just have a startup dialog that has the user select from a list of approved environments, set up the connection and use the connection throughout your solution.

On an unrelated matter, check out Dev Art's dotConnect.  If you work for a company (who can pay for it) and are doing Winforms, it may save you some deployment headaches over ODP.net.  Managed ODP.net is an improvement, but it doesn't yet support some of the more awesome features of Oracle, like bulk inserts/updates.

Answer (score 0):

As we dug farther and farther into c#, we cussed and discussed the various connections strings as settings etc.  As we learned more about table adapters and entities it was growing more and more complex to ensure everything was set up consistently throughout the whole application.  In the end I found this site and sample http://thecodemonk.com/2010/07/29/global-application-settings-override-now-with-examples/  (It had both a c# and vb example)

So I used the sample from the above in conjunction with a popup comboform dialog to select the proper environment when using the desktop application. So far it seems to be just what I was needing.

Thanks for all of the feedback!